# how to check the missing date from array with list of dates using java

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, validation, collections

all I have a date array which holds 15 days from today I want to validate missing date and trying to print it...

am building an API for front end chartjs bar chart for that am trying to get the count of records for 15 days from today if there are no records for a specific date or some dates are missing I will add 0 to the records for that am trying to print missing date

things I have done so far

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LocalDate Today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate checkDate = Today.minusDays(14);
        List<String> apiObj = new ArrayList<>();
        apiObj.add("2020-12-10");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-11");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-12");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-13");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-14");
//        apiObj.add("2020-12-15");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-16");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-17");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-18");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-19");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-20");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-21");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-22");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-23");
        apiObj.add("2020-12-24");


        for (int i = 0; i < apiObj.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("API DATA :  " + apiObj.get(i) + "  Check Date : " + checkDate);
            System.out.println("Logic Check :  " + checkDate.toString().equals(apiObj.get(i)));
            if (!checkDate.toString().equals(apiObj.get(i))) {
                System.out.println("Missing Date " + checkDate);
            }
           checkDate = checkDate.plusDays(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Everythings goes false after commented date

**OUTPUT which i get**

```
API DATA :  2020-12-10  Check Date : 2020-12-10
Logic Check :  true
API DATA :  2020-12-11  Check Date : 2020-12-11
Logic Check :  true
API DATA :  2020-12-12  Check Date : 2020-12-12
Logic Check :  true
API DATA :  2020-12-13  Check Date : 2020-12-13
Logic Check :  true
API DATA :  2020-12-14  Check Date : 2020-12-14
Logic Check :  true
API DATA :  2020-12-16  Check Date : 2020-12-15
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-15
API DATA :  2020-12-17  Check Date : 2020-12-16
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-16
API DATA :  2020-12-18  Check Date : 2020-12-17
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-17
API DATA :  2020-12-19  Check Date : 2020-12-18
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-18
API DATA :  2020-12-20  Check Date : 2020-12-19
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-19
API DATA :  2020-12-21  Check Date : 2020-12-20
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-20
API DATA :  2020-12-22  Check Date : 2020-12-21
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-21
API DATA :  2020-12-23  Check Date : 2020-12-22
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-22
API DATA :  2020-12-24  Check Date : 2020-12-23
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-23
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: What's the problem? Code seems like it should do the job. What errors do you get / what unexpected outputs do you get?

Comment: After the commented date, everything goes false

API DATA :  2020-12-14  Check Date : 2020-12-14
Logic Check :  true
API DATA :  2020-12-16  Check Date : 2020-12-15
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-15
API DATA :  2020-12-17  Check Date : 2020-12-16
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-16
API DATA :  2020-12-18  Check Date : 2020-12-17
Logic Check :  false
Missing Date 2020-12-17

Comment: Given that you add one day to the checkDate every time around the loop, how do you expect it to ever match after the missing day?

Comment: that's what am stuck with to get a solution

Answer (score 0):

You should change this part of your code

```
if (!checkDate.toString().equals(apiObj.get(i))) {
            System.out.println("Missing Date " + checkDate);
   }
```

To

```
if (!checkDate.toString().equals(apiObj.get(i))) {
            System.out.println("Missing Date " + checkDate);
            i--;
   }
```